# Плавное изменение между двумя текстурами в OpenGL

Tags: java, opengl

Есть текстура (предположим, это будет обычный текст на картинке). Нужно как-то добавить эффект "переливания" цвета, т.е. переход от одного цвета к другому. Пока смотрел классы GL11 ничего не нашел. Какой есть метод, или сторонние API?

Comment: Уточните, что такое эффект "transition" в вашем понимании.

Comment: "Переливание" цвета, т.е. переход от одного цвета к другому.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Самое простое - включить смешивание (glBlend) и рисовать сверху другую текстуру постепенно изменяя ее прозрачность.

```
glEnable(GL_BLEND); // Разрешить смешивание
glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA); // Типовой режим смешивания
glDepthFunc(GL_LEQUAL); // Режим наложения (рисуем то что равно или ближе)
```

Если используете современный OpenGL, то передавайте обе текстуры и время в шейдер, а там комбинируйте их как вам угодно.

Comment: Все сработало. Спасибо.